# Array value to string in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string

I've got some code which randomly fetches data from a database, but whenever I prints the data in the browser is looks like that  - ["data"]. I want it to be a clear string. How can I make that? Thank you!

Here is the code:

```
<?php 
   require '../wordbeater/adminpanel/includes/dbh.inc.php'; 

   $result=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 6");

   $count = 0;
   while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
       $postsarray["one.$count."] = $row[1];
       $postsarray["two.$count."] = $row[2];
       $count++;
   }

   $encodedArray = array_map(utf8_encode, $postsarray);
   echo $encodedArray;


   mysqli_close($con);

   ?>
```

Comment: Show us what you got and what you expected

Comment: use `implode`, not `array_map`

Comment: You cannot use `echo` on arrays - use `var_dump($encodedArray);`

Comment: Important question: is your data stored in ISO 8859-1 / Windows 1252 encoding? Because that's what utf8_encode assumes, and if not, it will mangle your text. Many people use it wrong (or just unnecessarily) because of its poor choice of name.

Comment: `array_map(utf8_encode, $postsarray)` - are you sure that line does not yield an error message? Where is that constant `utf8_encode` defined?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go for `mysqli_fetch_assoc` as it will give you the same associative array as like your database.
for e.g.

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
   $postsarray["one.$count."] = $row["column_name_u_want_to_fetch"];
   $postsarray["two.$count."] = $row["2_column_name_u_want_to_fetch"];
   $count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
   $result=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 6");

   $count = 0;

   while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
         $postsarray["one.$count."] = $row[1];
         $postsarray["two.$count."] = $row[2];
         $count++;
    }
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to that code such that others can learn from it

Answer (score -1):

You can directly store it in a variable so it will take it as a string.
for e.g.

```
$stringone="";
$stringtwo="";
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
$stringone.$count = $row["column_name_u_want_to_fetch"];
$stringtwo.$count = $row["2_column_name_u_want_to_fetch"];
$count++;

}

for($i=0; $i<mysqli_num_rows($result); $i++)
{

echo $stringone.$i;
echo $stringtwo.$i;
}
```

Comment: Now i got 00 as output.

Comment: `$stringone.$count` - what should that do? That looks pretty wrong to me

Answer (score -3):

try it by removing 'ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 6'

Comment: Please add some explanation to that code such that others can learn from it